# Rendering js.erb Layout but html.erb view file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view, render

When app gets javascript request it renders application.js.erb and index.js.erb by default, but i want to use index.html.erb and application.js.erb. How can i achieve that?

**I want to use :**

Application.js.erb + index.html.erb ***instead of***

Application.js.erb + index.js.erb

Comment: Why do you have index.js.erb in the first place if it is not supposed to be rendered by js requests?

Comment: i dont have, it says template is missing.

Answer (score 2):

add .html to end of partial name you want to render.

Example:

```
<%= render :partial=>'some_partial.html' %>
```

Instead of:

```
<%= render :partial=>'some_partial' %>
```

Comment: it is not partial. I use <% yield %>

Answer (score 0):

In your controller code you could

```
  def index
    #get records and whatnot

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js   { render :action=>:application }
    end
  end
```

Note: I don't know why you are doing this, but this will work. I recommend working within the rails standards.